# Why is a wchar_t* variable being clobbered?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, com

I'm working with the following piece of code. DLLName is of type `wchar_t*`, and it's being set early on in my program. Before i reach this point in my code, DLLName is a valid path to a DLL, like `L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\advapi32.dll"`

```
wprintf(L"Location: %s\n", DLLName);
HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibraryW(DLLName);
```

What happens when my code reaches `wprintf`? The value of DLLName is not printed. In fact, DLLName is now a blank string, `L""`! Which causes the call to `LoadLibraryW()` to fail.

Weird. I comment out `wprintf`. When the debugger reaches the `LoadLibraryW()`, DLLName is the correct wide string with the path to my DLL. After `LoadLibraryW()`, the value of DLLName is `L"\x4"`, and the call failed.

What's going on here? I am clueless on how to debug this.

EDIT: All of my code

```
BOOL FindOriginalCOMServer(wchar_t* GUID, wchar_t** DLLName)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    HKEY hCLSIDKey;
    wchar_t name[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD nameLength = MAX_PATH;

    wprintf(L"[*] Beginning search for GUID %s\n", GUID);

    LONG lResult = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, (LPCWSTR)L"SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        wprintf(L"[-] Error getting CLSID path\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Make sure HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\{GUID} exists
    lResult = RegOpenKeyExW(hKey, GUID, 0, KEY_READ, &hCLSIDKey);
    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        wprintf(L"[-] Error getting GUID path\n");
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Read the value of HKLM's InProcServer32
    lResult = RegGetValueW(hCLSIDKey, (LPCWSTR)L"InProcServer32", NULL, RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&name, &nameLength);
    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        wprintf(L"[-] Error getting InProcServer32 value: %d\n", lResult);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        RegCloseKey(hCLSIDKey);
        return FALSE;
    }

    *DLLName = name;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Then:

```
wchar_t* DLLName = new wchar_t[MAX_PATH];

if (!FindOriginalCOMServer((wchar_t*)lplpsz, &DLLName))
{
    wprintf(L"[-] Couldn't find original COM server\n");
    return S_FALSE;
}
wprintf("[+] Found original COM server: %s\n", DLLName);
HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibraryW(DLLName);
```

Comment: `*DLLName = name`. Here you leak the memory that you allocated and return a pointer to a locally allocated array that is destroyed as soon as the function returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DLLName` will point to a local char array in `FindOriginalCOMServer`, which will no longer exist once that function returns.

You should pass `DLLName` to `FindOriginalCOMServer()` as a `wchar_t*` (one pointer, not two) then get rid of `name` and work with `DLLName` directly.  Or, you could use `wcscpy_s()` to copy the string from `name` to `DLLName`.

Comment: Thanks! So if the value is destroyed after FindOriginalCOMServer returns, why was I able to correctly view the value of DLLName in my debugger after it returned?

Comment: @david because the memory hadn't been overwritten yet, but it had been technically freed and was available to be overwritten at any time, which is exactly what happened later